# Intuition for the inverse Hessian matrix

Tags: multivariable-calculus, approximation, curvature, hessian-matrix

Consider a function $f:\mathbb{R}^n\to\mathbb{R}$ and denote by $H$ its [Hessian matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hessian_matrix). I understand that $H$ provides a measure of the curvature of $f$ in all directions and plays a role in the Taylor approximation of $f$. But I keep encountering the inverse of $H$, and I was wondering if there is some intuition about $H^{-1}$? What does an element $H^{-1}_{ij}$ tell us about about the shape of $f$? Is there a geometric interpretation?

EDIT: Some examples where the inverse Hessian plays a role.

- For instance, in [maximum likelihood estimation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maximum_likelihood_estimation) the negative of the expected value of the Hessian of the log likelihood function is the [Fisher information](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fisher_information), and the inverse of that quantity gives us the covariance matrix of the estimated parameter.
- In [Newton's optimization method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newton%27s_method_in_optimization#:%7E:text=Newton%27s%20method%2C%20in%20its%20original,having%20more%20than%201%20point.), the inverse Hessian of the function tells us how big a step to take toward the optimum.

Comment: The spectrum of $H^{-1}$ is the spectrum of $H$ inverted.

Comment: @user_lambda It would probably be helpful if you gave us some examples where you encountered in the inverse of $H$.

Comment: @BenGrossmann I have added some examples. I'm hoping that there might be some more general geometric interpretation of $H^{-1}$.

Comment: For Newton’s optimization method, the inverse Hessian arises because $f’(x + v)\approx f’(x) + H_f(x)v$, and our next iteration uses the $v$ that makes this approximation equal to zero. Playing around with that idea might lead somewhere productive

Comment: In other words, it might be helpful to take these applications and frame things in terms of the Hessian. The question to ask, I think, is “what problem (in terms of the Hessian) does the inverse of the Hessian help us solve?”.

Comment: I think you already know that the Hessian encodes the curvature of the graph of $f$. I think that, in a sense, the inverse Hessian “accounts for” this curvature in some way